# Difference between dashes and slashes for date variables?

Tags: sql-server

There could be other factors in the DB that I'm unaware of, but I'm also basing this question on something a co-worker told me regarding this.

When declaring and setting a variable for dates, what's the difference between using dashes and slashes (and 0's), performance-wise?

```
DECLARE @START DATE

SET @START = '05-01-2020'
```

VS.

```
DECLARE @START DATE

SET @START = '5/1/2020'
```

Using the first, I was looking at 5 mins and counting for a query to return. When I remembered my co-worker telling me about using 0's and dashes, I then tried the first format and my query completed in about 2 mins. Is there a reason for this, or was it luck of the draw for DB resources?

Comment: Except for interpretation issues, the format of the string literal has no performance impact **IF** your example is an accurate representation of the "problem code". That's a big IF! Seems you have jumped to a conclusion - go back. Want to know why one query performs more efficiently than another? Compare the execution plans. Don't guess.

Answer (score 0):

The *similarity* between `05-01-2020` and `5/1/2020` is that both are non ISO, non standard, ways of writing date literals in SQL Server (or most other SQL databases).  The best way to write a date literal in SQL Server, for this example date, is:

```
20200501
```

This is an ISO format which will always be interpreted as 1st May, 2020, regardless of server settings.  In general, you should try to use this format when writing date literals in SQL Server.

Regarding performance, once a date literal is stored internally in SQL Server, it should not matter what string format was used to get it there.  Dates in SQL Server are stored as binary, and performance should not depend on the starting script to populate the data.